# What's the correct way to have multiple classes use the same parent class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have a project that has quite a lot of classes, stored as separate files, and some of them inherit the same parent class. The class in question is a settings class, it holds user preferences and such.

I am wondering: What is the correct way to have these classes use the same information?

For example...

Do I use `extends` each time? Or does `extends` execute and redefine code each time?

Do I instantiate the classes in new variables, like `$this->example = new Class();`, in each of the inheriting classes `__construct()` function? Or does that use more memory?

Do I somehow instantiate the classes in new variables in a different class and pass the variables to the inheriting classes via function parameters? Or is that bad form?

I just don't know!

---

settings.php looks like this:

```
class Settings
{
    public $pref = array();

    function __construct() {
        $this->pref['name'] = 'John';
        $this->pref['age'] = 21;
        $this->pref['display_dob'] = true;
        ...
    }
}
```

The inheriting classes look like this:

```
class ShowPerson extends Settings
{
    public function display()
    {
        echo $this->pref['name'], ' ';
        echo $this->pref['age'], ' years old';

        if ($this->pref['display_dob'] == true) {
            echo ' born ' . $this->pref['birth_date'], ' ';
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are doing with some concrete examples? It is hard to say specifically how you should setup your classes without know more about them.

Comment: Only one of your options is actually inheritance. Instantiating `$this->example = new Class` has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: mtinsley: Added some samples, hope they help. I'm trying to figure out if certain ways of inheriting perform badly or break testability.

Comment: @meagar He was not referring _instantiation of a class_ as being _inheritance_, he was merely suggesting to apply the approach of instantiation for passing on information over inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Inheritance is for extending classes that belong to the same type of class. For example:

```
Animal < Mammal < Primate < Human
```

How granular you make it (i.e. how many times you extend) depends on your needs.

The point, however, is that if a class has nothing to do with another class, or if they are only tangentially related, then they should not inherit from each other.

Something like settings should be passed to the class (i.e. the object).

So, paraphrasing the code in your question, you could do it like this:

```
// The settings should be created outside
$settings = new Settings;

// The settings are then provided to the new object
// Here we just pass it to the constructor, but you
// could also have something like a `useSettings()`
// method that sets it
$person = new Person($settings);
```

Extending code, like in your question, creates a tangled mess that you will be unable to untangle easily as your code matures. Writing self-contained units of code, and making use of interfaces, you can work on them separately and not worry about what the rest of your code does.